# CSC 101 Java Hangman Game

Tags: java

This is my first post on overflow, I apologize ahead of time for any amateur things I most likely will do.

I'm trying to write a simple program that will simulate the Hangman game.  My first thought was to store the users input into an array... but I am not sure how to go forward with the process.

Here are my questions:

- How do I mirror a user input with dashes? For example if a user input is: "hello this is my first post!"
- How do I then output a "----- ---- -- -- ---- -----"(including punctuation)
- Last question, how do I search a String for a character?

I am not looking to copy and paste someone else's code into my program.  But I am unsure of where to even start! I appreciate all input. Thanks.

Comment: Word of advice: you'll usually get better answers (and some more respect) if you show your attempted solution -- any attempt -- with your question and go into *exactly* where in the attempt you're having problems.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, Like I said this is my first post!  I don't have much code but I will put it in my post to show my attempt

Answer (score 1):

> How do I mirror a user input with dashes? For example if a user input is: "hello this is my first post!" How do I then output a "----- ---- -- -- ---- -----"(including punctuation)

**Hint**: you can create a string containing letters and hyphens (in the appropriate places) and then output it using `System.out.println`. Alternatively, you can call `System.out.print` for each character ... in a loop.

Figuring out exactly what you need to do here is part of your exercise.

> Last question, how do I search a String for a character?

**Hint**: using a loop and `charAt` is simplest.

**Hint**: you probably need to find *all* instances of the character ... not just the first or last one.

---

**Meta-hint**: you can find information about standard Java classes and methods by looking up the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

To mirror input with dashes (so, print out a dash for every character other than a space in a String), you could use an [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), looping through an `Array` of `Characters` created from the String the user entered, then for every character (unless it's a space), print out a dash.

Example (**if you want/need to see it**):

```
String textToOutput = "";
    for(char c : yourUsersInputString.toCharArray()) {
        if(c == ' ') {
            textToOutput+= " ";
        }
        else {
            textToOutput+= "-";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(textToOutput);
```

I imagine you could also use a Regex, but I'm not en expert in them myself, so I can't say for sure.

> how do I search a String for a character?

Not quite sure what you mean here, but you could use `.indexOf();` to check if there is *any 1 occurrence* of a character. You could also use a loop similar to the one above (`for-each`), looping on an `Array` created from your input string, and each time around the loop check if your character matches the current character from the `Array` (This is probably the better approach).